# Data Extension List REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

I want to list the **data extensions** contained in a **specific folder** in SFMC using **REST API**. 
I have already checked the documentation and I found a way to do it with SOAP API. But we need to do it with REST. Do you have any Idea please ?

Any help will be so much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: From a glance I think this is only available via REST using the internal SFMC REST API, which is not available to the end users as it requires a separate authentication process. You would need to use SOAP API for this in current state.

Comment: Hi Johnny, does it need to be REST API for any particular reason? Would this information be used on an external site, or could a Cloud Page work?

Comment: @CameronRobert Yes, it will be used in an external app and this app is using REST APIs. This why I'm looking for REST Solution.

Comment: If you need a solution; you could run a SSJS activity in a daily Automation that upserts a DE with the names of all of the Data Extensions in a specified folder, then use the REST API to get the rows from that “Upsert DE”. It would achieve the needs of your current questions.